# VBA - Función que devuelve un valor en una celda cuando cambia el valor de otra celda con scrollbar

Tags: excel, vba

La situación inicial seria la siguiente:

[image: Situación inicial]

Un valor inicial "A" en la columna X (el cual es el resultado de una función que depende de la scrollbar).

La función que estoy intentando encontrar es la que funcione de la siguiente manera:

1. Situación 1:
   En el momento que movemos la scrollbar hacia arriba (en este caso, solo de las dos primeras filas), ese valor de la columna X aumenta y el valor de la columna Z nos devuelve el 10% del valor de la columna de X:

[image: Situación que subimos la scrollbar]

2. Situación 2:
   Si en lugar de subir, bajamos la scrollbar de la situación inicial, el valor de la columna X disminuye y en Z nos aparece el -20% de ese valor.

[image: Situación que bajamos la scrollbar]

Por lo que se, necesito comparar el valor de la situación inicial con el nuevo valor (según situación 1 o 2) para poder devolver el valor correcto en Z.

Para ello, necesito crear una macro que al ejecutarla mediante un botón guarde el valor que hay en la columna X, de manera que la marque como situación inicial.

De esta manera fijamos la scrollbar en una posición como situación inicial (donde el valor de Z tendría que ser 0 como en la primera foto).

He intentado con este código, donde la macro guardar_previo guarda los valores iniciales("A") de toda la columna X. La función intenta compararlos con los valores nuevos ("B") de la misma columna y devolver el porcentaje correcto en caso de que hayan cambiado:

```
Option Explicit
Dim valorprevio() As Variant    
    Sub guardar_previo()

        Dim ultima_fila, n, i As Integer
            
        ultima_fila = Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
        n = Range("X1", "X" & ultima_fila).Count + 1
        ReDim valorprevio(n)
        For i = 0 To n
           valorprevio(i) = Range("X1").Offset(i + 1, 0)
        Next i
    End Sub
    ________________________
    Function porcentaje(valornuevo As Variant)
        Dim actual, antes As Variant
        Dim ultima_fila, n As Integer
    
        n = valornuevo.Row
        actual = valornuevo.Value
        antes = valorprevio(n)
        
        If actual <> antes Then
            If actual > antes Then
                porcentaje = -(actual / 10)
            Else
                porcentaje = (actual / 20)
            End If
        
        Else
            porcentaje = 0
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: La verdad es que estas esperando que te hagan el trabajo gratis, y eso no es el objetivo de esta página. Si necesitas ayuda, muestra algún progreso de tu parte, no se, un bosquejo de código o algo que diga que tú estas haciendo tu trabajo.

Comment: No pretendía eso ni mucho menos. Ahí tienes uno de muchos intentos de código que estoy probando....

Comment: No entiendo  del todo lo que quieres. Lo del 10% y el -20% sí pero A y B de dónde salen? ¿Son números que cambian? ¿Cuándo cambian? ¿Es un proceso iterativo o es algo de una sola vez?

Comment: "A" es el valor que hay en la columna X de la primera foto. Ese valor es el resultado de una función que depende de la scrollbar que hay en la columna Y. "B" es el valor nuevo de la columna X una vez se ha movido la scrollbar. Lo que pretendo es comparar el valor previo al cambio con el nuevo y, según sea mayor o menor, devolver en la columna Z un 10% o un -20% de este nuevo valor B.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner varios ejemplos numéricos del output esperado?

Comment: He editado la publicación intentando explicarme mejor. Espero aclarar las dudas :)